# Importar una variable desde otro shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Tengo una variable declarada en `scriptprincipal.sh`y necesito hacer uso de dicha variable en `scriptsecundario.sh`. ¿Hay alguna manera?

He probado a incluir el `scriptprincipal`, pero obviamente me ejecuta todo ese script, cosa que no necesito.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que cuando ejecutas un "ejecutable", este se corre en un proceso hijo aislado.

Algo que podrías hacer sería que ambos scripts tomen el valor pero de una **variable de entorno** que previamente exportaste con `export tu_variable="su valor"`,

Otra estrategia es utilizar un wrapper que ejecute esos dos scripts y dentro de ese wrapper definir dicha variable como una de entorno.

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es correr tu primer script (donde se encuentra tu variable) con `.` o con el alias `source`, es decir:

```
source scriptprincipal.sh
. scriptprincipal.sh
```

Y eso "cargará" el contenido de tu script dentro del mismo proceso que lo mandó a leer (y no en un subproceso hijo aislado), lo ejecutará línea por línea, y entonces la variable definida en tu script primario, suponiendo que diste la instrucción de exportarla, estará disponible para los demás subprocesos.

Comment: Comentario tiquismiquis: Si uno de los dos se puede llamar alias, sera el `source`, que es especifico a `bash` y este familia de shells, y no el `.` que es el único de los dos que [esta definido en POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot). En general, es mejor usar el `.` ya que con esto tu código sera mucho mas portable a sistemas y shells diferentes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094271/bash-using-dot-or-source-calling-another-script-what-is-difference

Answer (score 0):

Esa variable es local, global? Has pensado en escribirla en fichero en el otro script cada vez que lo ejecutes, y después con `scriptsecundario.sh` simplemente leerla de fichero?
Podrías declararla como variable global también en todas las bash

```
$ nombreVariable=prueba_variable_1
```

así podrías verla en cualquier script accediendo a ella

Answer (score 0):

Declaras las variables en el archivo X.

```
# Archivo x.sh 

VARIABLE_A=Variable_a
```

Después en el archivo Y donde quieras llamar a la variable del archivo X solo tienes que añadirla.

```
# Archivo y.sh 

. ./x.sh

echo $VARIABLE_A
```

No es necesario declarar el archivo como script de inicio, ni las variables a declarar como variables de entorno.